# Adding gmail.py increases conky's load time

Tags: 12.04, conky

I ma using `gmail.py` from [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Conky#Display_number_of_new_emails_.28Gmail.29) to display `new mail count` in gmail. The script works fine and displays my new mail count correctly.

The problem I am facing is when I restart conky after adding the above script to my `conky.config` conky took a little time`(arnd 4-5s)` to load and display. The reason I believe is `gmail.py` take sometime to fetch mail count thereby leading to conky's delay.
By delay I mean conky `display's` nothing for around `4-5s` when I run it.

Now, as soon as I remove `gmail.py` conky is back to normal.

So, I was thinking is there any in-built feature in conky which make sure that other conky objects like `cpu temp,uptime,date` etc are loaded and displayed while it executes `gmail.py` in background and than update conky accordingly.

*Relevant line in conky*:

```
Gmail: ${color red}${execpi 900 python /home/ranrag/.scripts/gmail.py}${color}
```

I am using `ubuntu 12.04` and `openbox`.

Comment: If it's just python, add a sleep command during init so it doesn't hold during run(or try relaunching since the conversion from py to pyc only happens on changes afaik).

Comment: @aking1012: Thanks. I am pretty new to linux so can you please elaborate a little on what do you mean by add a `sleep command during init`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a possible solution using `$texeci`. What it does is

> Runs a command at an interval inside a thread and displays the output.
>   Same as $execi, except the command is run inside a thread. Use this if
>   you have a slow script to keep Conky updating.

So, now when I run my conky it dislpays all my `conky objects` first and than it auto-fill `Gmail` field after a few seconds.

PS: I am still open to other alternative answers.